# Overstaying In Europe for about 2 years without knowing

Tags: europe, us-citizens, overstaying, sweden, permits

I went to Europe in early 2014 to visit a friend, I was 18 y/o and due to problems back home I ended up staying there for a year and then I left in late 2015 without any problems.

Then I went back to visit again in 2015 again got in without any problems and stayed another year and left in 2016, came back home without any problems.

But what I didn't know was that I could only stay there for 3 months on my passport because I never got in trouble or anything so I didn't think it was an issue. It's only now when I'm thinking about getting a work permit over there that I came to realize I need a resident permit, so I'm wondering.

What might happen if I apply for the work permit and resident permit since they need to see the stamps on my passport, what could possibly happen?

Comment: What is your nationality? When you write "Europe", do you mean the Schengen area in particular? Also, your shift key appears to be broken, and your period key stutters.

Comment: oh it was in sweden im a usa citizen

Comment: its been over 6 months since ive been back btw

Comment: And what country's visa are you applying for now? Sweden again or somewhere else?

Comment: I find it very hard to believe you "didn't know" - one overstay maybe, but what did you tell the immigration officers about your plans when you came in the second time? (BTW stamps in your passport are not the only way they'll have to track you)

Comment: It would surprise me greatly if they even notice, and if they do they will likely inform you of the rules, nothing else. Other repercussions would be unthinkable if you ask me. If you are super worried, get a new passport.